# Excel VBA - Como usar VLookup com Letras e Números para Deletar Filas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá!
Estou passando por grande dificuldade com um problema utilizando VLookup no VBA do Excel. Antes de mais nada, eu não sou expert em VBA porém consegui usar o VLookup mas não estou tendo o efeito que gostaria. 
Vou explicar abaixo com maiores detalhes a situação com imagens:

1. Estou com uma tabela que associa letras à números em uma planilha separada. Fiz isso pois eu preciso quantificar letras para depois poder compará-las.

[image: Tabela 1]

2. Com esta tabela, pretendo permitir que o usuário, na planilha principal, insira valores que corresponderão à códigos que contém uma combinação de números e letras (Ex: 91V). E depois, com um macro, escolha um valor de código (Ex: 89H).
   Assim, eu gostaria de criar um macro que iria deletar filas da tabela que neste código tenham números maiores que o escolhido e letras com valores menores.
   Exemplo da tabela inserida:

[image: Tabela 2]

3. Eu estava tentando juntar informações e montei um código que permite que o usuário insira um valor (Ex: 91V) usa o VLookup pra procurar o valor de V. Porém não vou muito além disso.

Poderiam me ajudar?

**EDIT:**

À pedido, este era o código que eu tinha até então. Porém, ele era um trabalho em processo que logicamente não está nem perto do que eu preciso.

```
Sub DeletarIndices()

    indice = InputBox("Digite o Valor Desejado", "Teste")

    Set planilhaV = Sheets("IV")
    Dim vValores As String
    sResult = Application.VLookup(indice, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not (Range("A" & i).Value > sResult) Then
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

Meu código agora está assim:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeletarIndices()

    Dim indice As String   ' To hold our user input letter
    Dim indiceValue As Long   ' To hold the numeric value of our user input letter
    Dim rowLetter As String   ' To hold the current row letter
    Dim rowLetterValue As Long   ' To hold the numeric value of the current row letter
    Dim firstRow As Long   ' First row of your data
    Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last row of your data
    Dim currentRow As Long   ' Current row for your loop counter
    Dim sht As Worksheet   ' To hold the worksheet you're working on
    Dim planilhaV As Worksheet   ' To hold your lookup worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")   ' Use the name of your worksheet
    Set planilhaV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IV")   ' As in your original example
    firstRow = 1
    lastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    indice = UCase(InputBox("Digite o IC/IV Desejado", "Teste"))   ' Convert user input to upper case and store
    indiceValue = CLng(Application.VLookup(indice, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2, False))   ' Creating numeric indice value with lookup table

    For currentRow = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
        rowLetter = UCase(Right(sht.Range("A" & currentRow).Value, 1))   ' Get letter from code in column A, converted to upper case
        rowLetterValue = CLng(Application.VLookup(rowLetter, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2, False))   ' Creating numeric value for current row letter with lookup table
        If rowLetterValue < indiceValue Then   ' Compare the numeric letter values, and if smaller than user input...
            sht.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete   ' Delete the row
        End If
    Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Agora eu precisaria apenas de uma ajuda para adaptar este código com um incremento. Eu preciso permitir o usuário a inserir não apenas uma letra, mas um código (Ex: 91T). Para finalizar, eu preciso que ao inserir o exemplo "91T", o código exclua da tabela todas as linhas que incluam Letras Menores e Números Maiores.

Comment: Adicione o código que você colocou. o VLookup é o PROCV em ptBr. Uma dica para quem não conhece muito de VBA é fazer a função funcionar enquanto grava uma macro, assim você consegue entender melhor como o excel trabalha.

Comment: Olá Celso. Adicionei o código de até então. Porém no VBA, se usa o VLookup mesmo. E o que procuro é muito complexo para se fazer via gravação de macro.

Comment: Olá Leon. A sua pergunta é um pouco confusa por causa dos exemplos. Na tabela principal que você exemplifica (primeira imagem) não tem um código 91V. Esse código vai estar lá ou será uma concatenação de "91" + "V" (sendo que o "código" seria mesmo o "V")? Agora, supondo que é isso mesmo, o que ele faz depois que acha "o valor de V"? Pra que esse valor serve na seleção ou exclusão dos dados originais? Não está claro.

Comment: Olá @LuizVieira! Vou tentar te passar um passo-a-passo do que deve acontecer. -- 1. O cliente insere um código após rodar o macro (Ex: 91V). -- 2. Esse código deve ser quebrado entre o número e letra (Ex: 91 e V). -- 3. A letra terá seu valor retirado da tabela. (Ex: V = 7). -- 4. O valor do número (Ex: 91) e o da letra (Ex: 7) será comparado com a lista da tabela original. Os números com números e as letras com letras, baseado nos seus valores numéricos. -- 5. As linhas da tabela que tiverem números menores E as com letras menores devem ser cortadas.

Comment: Por "tabela original" vc quer dizer a tabela da primeira figura? Lá também não tem número 91...

Comment: Eis o que eu estou entendendo: o seu código é formado por duas partes, uma numérica com dois dígitos (ex: "91") e uma alfabética com um dígito (ex.: "V"). Você tem vários desses códigos numa tabela qualquer, e quer construir uma função que automaticamente delete linhas cujo código esteja num intervalo dado pelo usuário.

Comment: O intervalo vai ser dado com uma parte numérica que vai ser o limite **inferior** e uma parte alfabética que vai ser o limite **superior** da exclusão. Ou seja, se o usuário informar "89H", o que ele quer é apagar as linhas com códigos que vão de "90[A,B,C,...,G]" ==> "[91,92,93,...]G". É isso?

Comment: @LuizVieira Exatamente! Os valores das letras estão na primeira tabela que estão em uma folha separada! Por enquanto com o nome de "IV". A razão disso é porque as letras não seguem uma ordem alfabética, então tive que quantificá-las.

Comment: Ok, eu respondi com uma sugestão de implementação. Não reaproveitei o seu código porque eu tinha tanta sugestões pra passar que foi mais fácil refazer. No futuro, procure explicar melhor o seu problema (dê exemplos mais fáceis de serem acompanhados) e crie um [mcve] que alguém possa baixar e testar ou construir em cima. Se não, fica difícil obter ajuda nesses casos. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis um exemplo de código que faz o que você quer:

```
' Verifica se um dado dígito é um número. Retorna True se for, False se não for.
Function ehNumero(ByVal digito As String) As Boolean

    a = Asc(digito)
    If a >= 48 And a <= 57 Then
        ehNumero = True
    Else
        enNumero = False
    End If

End Function

' Separa o código em duas partes, uma numérica e uma alfabética
Function separaCodigo(ByVal codigo As String, ByRef numero As Integer, ByRef letras As String) As Boolean
    p = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(codigo)
        digito = Mid(codigo, i, 1)
        If Not ehNumero(digito) Then ' Achou o ponto de quebra quando encontrar o primeiro dígito não numérico
            p = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If p = 0 Or p = 1 Then
        numero = 0
        letras = ""
        separaCodigo = False
    Else
        codigo = UCase(codigo)
        numero = Int(Mid(codigo, 1, p - 1))
        letras = Mid(codigo, p)
        separaCodigo = True
    End If
End Function

' Obtém o valor de uma sequencia de letras na tabela de códigos da configuração
Function valorDasLetras(ByVal letras As String) As Integer
    On Error GoTo trataErro

    valorDasLetras = Application.VLookup(letras, Range("códigos"), 2, False) ' O último parâmetro (False) é FUNDAMENTAL!

    ' Você também pode fazer assim:
    'valorDasLetras = Application.VLookup(letras, Worksheets("Configuração").Range("A2:B11"), 2, False)
    ' Mas é muito melhor ter a definição dos limites num lugar só, por isso use uma tabela nomeada como acima

    Exit Function

trataErro:
    valorDasLetras = 0 ' As letras não existem na tabela de configuração

End Function

'Deleta as linhas da tabela que estejam entre o intervalo dado pelo número de limite inferior e pela letra de limite superior
'Retorna a quantidade de linhas excluidas
Function deletar(ByVal numero As Integer, letras As String) As Integer

    ' Pega o valor das letras do código na tabela de configuração
    valor = valorDasLetras(letras)
    If valor = 0 Then ' O código não foi encontrado
        deletar = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Define os limites inferior e superior para a deleção
    limInf = numero
    limSup = valor

    ' Seleciona as linhas que serão deletadas da planilha de dados, conforme elas se encaixarem nos limites definidos
    Dim dados As Worksheet
    Set dados = Application.Worksheets("Dados")

    Dim linhasPraDeletar As Range ' Vai guardar as linhas a serem deletadas
    totalLinhas = 0

    linha = 1
    Do While True
        ' Pega o código da linha atual
        curCodigo = dados.Cells(linha, 1) ' Eu coloquei na coluna A pra facilitar o teste

        ' Termina se acabaram os dados da planilha
        If curCodigo = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        ' Separa o código da linha atual em número + letras
        Dim curNumero As Integer
        Dim curLetras As String
        If Not separaCodigo(curCodigo, curNumero, curLetras) Then
            deletar = -1
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Pega o valor das letras do código na tabela de configuração
        curValor = valorDasLetras(curLetras)
        If curValor = 0 Then ' O código não foi encontrado
            deletar = -1
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Verifica se o número e as letras estão no intervalo desejado
        ' Se estiver, seleciona toda a linha
        If curNumero > limInf And curValor < limSup Then
            If linhasPraDeletar Is Nothing Then
                Set linhasPraDeletar = dados.Rows(linha)
            Else
                Set linhasPraDeletar = Union(linhasPraDeletar, dados.Rows(linha))
            End If
            totalLinhas = totalLinhas + 1
        End If

        linha = linha + 1
    Loop

    if totalLinhas > 0 Then
        'Set salva = ActiveCell ' <=========== (1)

        linhasPraDeletar.Select
        'linhasPraDeletar.EntireRow.Delete ' <===== Descomente essa linha pra fazer a exclusão de fato

        'salva.Select ' <============= Descomente essa linha e a linha (1) lá em cima para guardar e voltar a célula de seleção atual do usuário
    End If

    deletar = totalLinhas

End Function

' Função atribuída ao clique do botão, para teste
Sub BotãoDeletar_Clique()
    'On Error GoTo trataErro

    ' Lê o código do usuário
    msg = "Digite o código de delimitação do filtro no formato 99XX (sendo que 99 é o número do limite inferior e XX é a letra do limite superior):"
    codigo = InputBox(msg, "Código")
    If codigo = "" Then ' Cancelado
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Separa o código no número + letras
    Dim numero As Integer
    Dim letras As String
    If Not separaCodigo(codigo, numero, letras) Then
        MsgBox ("Código inválido: " & codigo)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Chama a função de deleção
    linhas = deletar(numero, letras)
    If linhas = -1 Then
        MsgBox ("Há um error com um código (a letra não existe na configuração)")
    Else
        If linhas = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Não há linhas no intervalo requisitado - nenhuma linha foi deletada")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Foi(ram) deletada(s) " & linhas & " linha(s)")
        End If
    End If

    Exit Sub

trataErro:
    MsgBox ("O código não está no formato esperado.")

End Sub
```

A explicação dele tá nos comentários, mas basicamente o que ele faz é:

1. Lê o código informado pelo usuário.
2. Separa o número e as letras que serão usados para definir os limites de pesquisa. Também obtém o valor da sequencia de letras na tabela de configuração (usando `vlookup` **exato** - para isso o último parâmetro precisa precisa ser `False`).
3. Varre a tabela de dados linha por linha.
4. Em cada linha, verifica se o código dela se encontra dentro dos limites, fazendo o mesmo processo de separação em 2. Se se encontra, salva essa linha para usar depois (e acumula uma variável usada para retornar a quantidade de linhas)
5. No final, seleciona as linhas que vão ser deletadas e as exclui.

> Duas observações importantes. A primeira é que no código a exclusão tá
>   comentada (assim como os códigos que salvam e restauram a posição
>   originalmente selecionada do usuário) para que a seleção realizada
>   para a exclusão permaneça ativa para você depurar visualmente! A
>   segunda observação é que esse código usa uma [tabela nomeada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMTPniMAfho) pra
>   que o intervalo de células não fique fixo no código (hard-coded). Isso
>   facilita muito a manutenção futura:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado usando o código `"89H"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Parece que o que você fez está perfeito, embora aqui não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar. Botei os nomes das páginas conforme os seus: "Dados e códigos", mas mesmo assim, sempre fico com o seguinte erro: "Há um error com um código ( a letra não existe na configuração)

Comment: A página não chama "códigos". Esse é o nome da tabela. Veja a figura com o círculo em vermelho. A única página que usa o nome é a "dados". A outra página eu chamei de "Configuração", mas tanto faz porque o programa usa o nome da tabela, e não da página.

Comment: Ah, e se a resposta te ajudar, considere marcá-la como aceita: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Muito obrigado! Acho que agora ficou perfeito. Fiz apenas umas alterações nesta linha para alcançar exatamente o que eu queria: `If curNumero > limInf Or curValor < limSup Then`

Comment: Se puder me resolver mais uma dúvida. Quando eu faço o teste com "91H" eu vejo o seguinte erro: `A variável do objeto ou a variável do bloco Width não foi definida` -- Descobri apenas com esse código inserido.

Comment: Não sei de que código inserido vc fala. Esse erro diz que um objeto não foi definido. Provavelmente você cometeu algum erro no código que alterou. Volte e revise. E se é outro problema, abra outra pergunta. Lembre-se: *este site não é um fórum*.

Comment: É apenas nesse caso mesmo. As mudanças que fiz foram apenas na alteração dos < e >. Funciona perfeitamente com qualquer outro código. Notei apenas quando clico no botão e me pede um código, SE eu digitar "91H" e rodar, aparece este erro. Funciona com qualquer outro valor, como o seu "89H".

Comment: Em que linha dá o erro? Você depurou? (isto é, abriu o código, colocou ponto de parada e executou passo a passo pra ver o que tá acontecendo) Uma mudança só no < e > não deveria gerar **esse** erro. Pode ter outro problema no meu código original que eu não percebi aqui. Sem mais informações, é impossível te ajudar além disso. Vc precisa fazer um pouco da sua lição de casa. Sugiro depurar mesmo. Vai te ajudar até mesmo a entender como o código funciona.

Comment: Ah, eu acho que entendi o que vc fez. Vc trocou a ordem da comparação (de `curNumero > limInf Or curValor < limSup` para `curNumero < limInf Or curValor > limSup`). Foi isso? Nesse caso, pode ser que não esteja retornando linha alguma, e falhando na chamada de `linhasPraDeletar.Select`. Faça uma alteração para garantir que não dá erro verificando o valor de `totalLinhas`. Vou alterar na resposta.

Comment: Fiz uma edição para adicionar um `if totalLinhas > 0 Then` ali no final da função de deleção. Vai impedir o erro de ocorrer. Mas verifique se faz sentido essa sua alteração de operadores de comparação. Não é o entendimento que eu havia entendido de vc no começo e vai considerar os limites *de forma inversa*.