# Como Deletar Filas Com Código Inserido Pelo Usuário?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

A pouco tempo fiz **[esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182600/28595)** que não obteve respostas:

Porém obtive certo auxílio de algumas pessoas e pude evoluir o código até certo ponto.

Meu código agora está assim:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeletarIndices()

    Dim indice As String   ' To hold our user input letter
    Dim indiceValue As Long   ' To hold the numeric value of our user input letter
    Dim rowLetter As String   ' To hold the current row letter
    Dim rowLetterValue As Long   ' To hold the numeric value of the current row letter
    Dim firstRow As Long   ' First row of your data
    Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last row of your data
    Dim currentRow As Long   ' Current row for your loop counter
    Dim sht As Worksheet   ' To hold the worksheet you're working on
    Dim planilhaV As Worksheet   ' To hold your lookup worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")   ' Use the name of your worksheet
    Set planilhaV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IV")   ' As in your original example
    firstRow = 1
    lastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    indice = UCase(InputBox("Digite o IC/IV Desejado", "GBG Pneus"))   ' Convert user input to upper case and store
    indiceValue = CLng(Application.VLookup(indice, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2, False))   ' Creating numeric indice value with lookup table

    For currentRow = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
        rowLetter = UCase(Right(sht.Range("A" & currentRow).Value, 1))   ' Get letter from code in column A, converted to upper case
        rowLetterValue = CLng(Application.VLookup(rowLetter, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2, False))   ' Creating numeric value for current row letter with lookup table
        If rowLetterValue < indiceValue Then   ' Compare the numeric letter values, and if smaller than user input...
            sht.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete   ' Delete the row
        End If
    Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Agora eu precisaria apenas de uma ajuda para adaptar este código com um incremento. Eu preciso permitir o usuário a inserir não apenas uma letra, mas um código (Ex: 91T). Para finalizar, eu preciso que ao inserir o exemplo "91T", o código exclua da tabela todas as linhas que incluam Letras Menores e Números Maiores.

Comment: Removi o texto da outra pergunta, uma vez que você a linkou nesta, o que torna desnecessário o texto dela nesta aqui.

Comment: Ok! Desculpa! Sou novo aquI!

Comment: Essa pergunta está me parecendo a mesma da anterior. Você "evoluiu" o problema, mas a dúvida continua a mesma, não?

Comment: O objetivo final continua o mesmo, mas eu passei por grandes alterações no código. De repente com o que tenho agora alguém possa dar somente a peça final.

Comment: Bom, se o objetivo é o mesmo, você não devia abrir duas perguntas. Poderia ter editado aquela. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask]. Eu vou votar pra fechar essa como duplicada daquela, ok? Tenta melhorar lá pra que possamos te ajudar. :)